# Does pointwise convergence imply convergence in $\mathfrak{L}^{\text{loc}}_{1}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^{q})$?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

I want to know if pointwise convergence implies convergence in $\mathfrak{L}^{\text{loc}}_{1}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^{q})$.

Let $\{w_{k}\}$ be pointwise convergent. Then $$\lim_{k\to\infty}w_{k}(t)=w(t)$$.

If $\{w_{k}\}$ is convergent in $\mathfrak{L}^{\text{loc}}_{1}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^{q})$, then $\forall a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{a}^{b}\|w(t)-w_{k}(t)\|dt=0$$

Since $\{w_{k}\}\to w$ as $k\to\infty$, the equation above is equivalent to $$\int_{b}^{b}\|w(t)-w(t)\|dt=\int_{a}^{b}\|0\|dt=0$$

But I think I've done this wrong since this seems too straightforward.

Comment: consider $n \mathbb 1_{(0, 1/n)}$

Comment: @user251257 What does that denote?

Comment: $\mathbb 1_{(0, 1/n)}$ denotes the indicator function of the open interval $(0, 1/n)$.

Comment: So if I take $w_{n}(t)=n 1_{(0,1/n)}(t)$ and then prove by counterexample? But I'm having some trouble understanding the pointwise limit of the indicator function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n\in\mathbb N\setminus\{0\}$ consider the function
$$ w_n(t) = \begin{cases} n, & 0 < t < 1/n, \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases} $$

The interval $(0, 1/n)$ is decreasing and converges to $\emptyset$. So the pointwise limit of $w_n$ is the $0$ function.

Now, let $a < b$ be given. We either have $[a,b] \cap (0, 1/n) = \emptyset$ or $a < 0 < b$. In the first case, we have trivially $\int_a^b w_n = 0$. In the second case, for $n$ sufficiently large, we have $a < 0 < 1/n < b$.
However, $\int_a^b w_n = 1$. So, $w_n$ does not converges to $0$ in $L^1[a,b]$.

So pointwise convergence does not imply local convergence in $L^1$.